# Start kodi from the terminal of another user

Tags: session, fuse, kodi

I'm trying to work around an issue I have with hidden fuse files locked by kodi.bin. Please note that I'm already trying to resolve the root cause for the actual issue through other threads but havn't been successful at it yet (it's probably an issue with kodi or more likely its extension vfs.rar).

**Some context:**

- 1 computer running under Ubuntu 22.04
- when I boot the computer, 1 user (let's call it "kodiuser") auto logs in and start kodi as a standalone session
- kodi is set to use the extension vfs.rar to watch movies that are stored in rar files
- right now, after I'm done with the movie, I can't delete the folder of this movie until I have restarted kodi, which is not handy because of the kodi standalone session (so I usually user the kodi remote on my phone to reboot the server) - this is due to the fact that kodi hasn't released some of the files

**What I'd like to do:**

- connect to the computer terminal as the user "kodiuser" maybe (or another one that is sudoer?)
- kill kodi.bin
- restart kodi

**Problem:**
Because it is set to a kodi standalone session, when kodi.bin is killed it gets me to the ubuntu user connection landing page (sorry I don't know how to call this properly, but that's where you have to log in with a user to open a linux graphical session)

-> I think that this implies that in addition to killing it I should start a new standalone kodi session from this same command line, which should equal to restarting kodi.

What do you think? Any guidance to the command line I would have to execute if this is doable?

I hope this is clear.

Thanks in advance.